# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing randomly and freezes on shutdown and reboot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, shutdown

I recently set up a dual boot on my new laptop with an i7 8750h and a laptop grade gtx 1050, with Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10.

[image: uname -r shows 4.18.7-041807]

Any time I try shutting the machine down or rebooting it does not work. I tried a bunch of things like editing the grub config file and disabling secure boot and fast boot.

[image: screenshot of /etc/default/grub with intel_idle.max_cstate=1 parameter]

What else can I try?

Comment: The parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` only fixes freezing problems for Bay Trail processors, of which yours is not one. I have not heard of this helping anyone with an i7. Can you please tell us if you have this problem with the standard Ubuntu kernel? Why did you install the 4.18? Was it to fix this? I assume your CPU uses i915. Not sure of the current status but there are frequent patches and regressions so you might well find YMMV with different kernels

Comment: You might try running the standard, supported, 4.15 kernel. 4.18 is not supported here. Sorry.

Comment: I was on 4.15 and it was still happening... I updated the kernel in Hope's of there may have been a fix... I also believe that my CPU is i915

Comment: There was also a post on here saying to change the parameter in the /etc/default/grub file called  grub_cmdline_default_linux from the default to acpi=force... not sure what that does but it didnt work either.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking about a problem you have running Ubuntu with a non-standard kernel. There is a consensus that such questions are not off-topic.

Comment: You know, there are a lot of kernel boot parameters and you'll have a long job just testing every one ;) please share where you're getting suggestions. i915 is the Intel CPU driver. I've heard about freezes on i7 series CPUs, but the problem could also be a graphics card or something else. Do you see any interesting messages when you attempt to shut down? You might try adding some debug parameters like `initcall_debug` and `no_console_suspend` to see more messages. Also check your `/var/log/syslog`. If the new kernel is no better, use the standard one. Please [edit] your question if you have n

Comment: Also, please copy and paste text from your terminal and format as code by selecting the text and pressing Ctrl+k or the `{}` button, instead of posting screenshots of text

Comment: actually after 2-3 days of slamming my face into ubuntu i was able to fix it... the fix involved going to /etc/default/grub and changing the default line to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noacpi"... also other parameters like disabling fast boot and secure boot

Answer (score 1):

The fix involved going to `/etc/default/grub` and changing the default line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noacpi"` and then running `sudo update-grub`.

I also disabled fast boot and secure boot.

Comment: Did it in my recently installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS, it started to log to screen boot process and then crashed in an hour. Will try my luck with fast boot and secure boot. You may add your recommendations about them to your answer as well. Did it all the trick to avoid freezes in 18.04 for you BTW?