# How to fix Ubuntu 18.04LTS freezes?

Tags: freeze, crash, bug-reporting, console, reset

I've installed latest Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS about a week ago.
All the soft was installed via system menu or Jetbrains repo.

In 2 days appeared freezes - only mouse moves, irresponsive to keyboard, timer above the window don't tick. For several days it was 1 freeze a day in the evening, then 2 freezes in the evening, yesterday 5 freezes, today - 5 times.

I daily do update/upgrade.

My keyboard don't have SysReq button.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd> worked only once, once <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> added somewhat in appeared console stream.

I googled around and find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075328/ubuntu-18-04-freezing-randomly-and-freezes-on-shutdown-and-reboot) advising to get to `/etc/default/grub` and changing the default line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noacpi"` and then running `sudo update-grub`.

Then i had my 5 freezes yesterday.
Sometimes after crash Ubuntu asks for sending crash report, sometimes not.

My questions are:

1. How to get to console and collect info/reason for a crash?
2. Is it possible to recover from crash without reset or power down button?
3. How to properly collect info/reason for a crash to send it to Ubuntu
   (preferably automatically)?

There is an advice to change kernel in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751148/ubuntu-freezes-a-few-minutes-after-login?rq=1).
The kernel in my setup is 4.15.0-39-generic. But it is not in a [list of available stable kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/ExtendedStable).

Should I change to another kernel in order to get stable system?

**Update 2018-11-29**

```
    /var/crash$ ls -alt /var/crash
total 25864
-rw-r-----  1 gdm       whoopsie 19808573 ноя 29 09:38 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash
drwxrwsrwt  2 root      whoopsie     4096 ноя 29 09:27 .
----------  1 gdm       whoopsie  1810565 ноя 28 15:16 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie  whoopsie        0 ноя 28 14:07 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root      whoopsie        0 ноя 28 14:04 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie  whoopsie        0 ноя 28 10:08 _usr_share_stacer_stacer.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r--  1 home-user whoopsie        0 ноя 28 10:05 _usr_share_stacer_stacer.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 home-user whoopsie  4845874 ноя 28 10:05 _usr_share_stacer_stacer.1000.crash
drwxr-xr-x 15 root      root         4096 ноя 20 20:09 ..
```

and

```
/var/crash$ sudo ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
[sudo] password for home-user: 
ls: cannot access '/home/home-user/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
```

and

```
/var/crash$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        3,1G         25G        118M        3,0G         27G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G
```

Yes, memtest does appear in my GRUB menu. I'll give it a try tonight.
Dual-boot Windows 7 don't show any problems so far.

Just have found [quite similar issue with LibreOffice 5.1 / Ubuntu 16.04:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964576/libreoffice-5-1-6-2-crashes-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit)

Turned off Java in my LibreOffice, OpenCL already off. 
No luck. 3 freezes in 2 hours. Last time touching LibreOffice after a pause freeze everything but mouse again.
Installed NVidia driver v.340.
Let' see.

Comment: In `terminal` do `ls -alt /var/crash` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h`. Copy/paste that output into your original question. Does `memtest` appear in your GRUB menu? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @user535733 Updated my post. I did try to investigate /var/log/syslog after some of first freezes. Logging did continue during the freeze. I will try to repeat it later, right after crash.

Comment: @ heynnema. Updated my post.